# Wouldn't the use of WayneTech by Bane fully expose Bruce Wayne's identity as Batman?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

As everyone sifts through the rubble of Gotham after retaking the city, it quickly becomes clear that the Tumblers used by Bane's forces were manufactured by Wayne Enterprises. They're all the same, precise design as Batman's super-car...it becomes public knowledge that the Bat was Wayne technology as well.

Batman (apparently) died, Bruce Wayne disappeared...how can anyone doubt that Wayne was Batman? Plus, Batman showed up just as Bruce Wayne reappeared. I can see how you might miss that at the time, but in retrospect...plus Coleman Reese, now no longer necessarily bound by gratitude to Wayne....

Is there another angle to this, or is it utterly clear to everyone in the world who Batman was?

Comment: When did it become clear the tumblers were Waybe tech? Were there logos I didn't see?

Comment: Even if the name wasn't directly stamped on the vehicle, there would be an investigation that would track down where they came from. And in any case, there's still the Bat.

Comment: Also who's to say that Coleman Reese survived the purge of the wealthy elite of Gotham during the time it was run by the League of Shadows?

Comment: Yeah, I almost wrote "assuming that he survived". I can see his type going pretty early in the purge...

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I can't think of too many times in the movie where the Bat was seen in broad daylight, besides the last part where he flies away with the bomb. And even with that, Fox could claim WayneTech was in league with the Batman once the city fell.

Comment: Also being the genius he is, Lucius Fox more than likely offered Wayne Enterprises resources to aid in the reconstruction/clean up of Gotham which would conveniently allow for him to retake any parts that might link Bruce to the equipment.

Comment: @ThomBrannan:   I thought you meant FoxNews, not Lucius Fox.  :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using WayneTech doesn't make Wayne Batman in people's eyes.  Bane uses more WayneTech and does it in the open, and noone would think for a second he is Bruce.  Wayne is a feeble hermit at this point, so noone would even think he was capable of any of these actions.  As for the Batman Dies, Bruce disappears argument.  Most of Gotham's wealthy were executed, not to mention all the others that died or disappeared during the events of Rises.  He was just a name on a LONG list of casualties.

Comment: +1 Batman has to get his gear from *somewhere*; if Wayne Enterprises produces the best quality stuff it would be perfectly logical that he would use it.

Comment: Not sure this comment deserves its own answer, because yours is good, but here goes: the closest anyone might come to putting two and two together is when the Wayne engineers are talking with Lucius and observe that Bruce Wayne checked in the fix for the autopilot. Having that sort of technical ability might seem out of step with Bruce's public persona. But these were just two employees, and it's still a big leap from "smarter than we thought" to "he is the night".

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak regarding the comics themselves, but in multiple episodes of Batman: The Animated Series, villains have operated using tech developed for/by, or just stolen from other companies - sometimes from Wayne Enterprises itself.

Even if someone (eg: Coleman Reese) publicly tried to link Bruce and Batman, the idea could be floated that either the tech/equipment had been stolen or that Bruce was acting as a sort of sponsor/supplier to Batman.

Comment: The "sponsor" idea was sort of the premise behind Batman Inc.